# ios aws sdk cloudfront image downloading and video streaming

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stream, amazon-cloudfront

I'm building an app that require to use Amazon web services. I've uploaded images to Amazon S3 buckets. Now i need to download them though CloudFront. 
I've set up 2 cloud front distribution urls (for images and videos, like xxx.cloudfront.net).

My question is how to proceed further?

Are there any classes in the AWS iOS SDK that can do this, or i have to create my own requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can help you :

```
S3GetObjectRequest *getObjectRequest = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:nameImage withBucket:@"nameBuckets"];

S3GetObjectResponse *getObjectResponse = [[AmazonClientManager s3] getObject:getObjectRequest];

UIImage *tampon = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:getObjectResponse.body];
```

Comment: This is only for downloading the file from S3..not from cloudfront